# What is property change value of JOptionPane and When it changes?

Tags: java, swing

I see that when creating a customized dialog with JOptionPane, in the method propertyChange that handle property change events, people often check whether the current property value equals a certain value, say VALUE_PROPERTY. And after that they would check which button in the dialog the user choose.

So what is the property value?

Specifically, what is the meaning of VALUE_PROPERTY and INPUT_VALUE_PROPERTY?

What does a user do to change the property value?

Comment: Typically, if you're at this level I'd be questing your approach(15+ years I've never needed to do this), but since you've provided no context it's impossible to know. VALUE_PROPERTY is used by the option dialog to detect when the user presses a button, the property event is raised in response so that the api can make decisions about what it should do (typically closing the dialog)

Answer (score 1):

It is not that complicated. The show dialog method returns an integer. With this value you are able to understand what the user selected:

For instance,

```
YES_OPTION, means that the user clicked yes.
```

So, how is this translated to the logic?

If you were implementing a listener, you would do something like this:

```
if(the user selected yes)
    //do something
```

You can read more about it here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Comment: Thanks. But how about the other values I mention? What does they mean?

Comment: They are the same. The only difference are the names of the variables. For listeners, you would use an input_value because you are expecting input from the user. Try some tutorials first and you will get the idea.